# Unable to delete annotation from pdf

Tags: pdf, annotations

Deleted annotation from pdf but still able to see that annotation in any viewer. What must be wrong in incremental update?

Attached pdf is http://www.filedropper.com/gettingstartedadobeencryptedtempannotations.
Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup for the annotation was not deleted. That's why (depending on the logic of the reader application) there's still a chance that the annotation is shown. At the end the annotation itself still exists and refereces to the page via its P entry (while it is missing in the annotations array):

[image: Screenshot Acrobat]

You can see that the "deleted" comment (blue) is still availabe in the annotation structure:

[image: pdf structure]

So at the end you simply have to delete the popup annotation (183), too.

Answer (score 3):

I extracted the former revision of your file and compared the first page of it with the first page of the final revision with each other as seen in Adobe Reader:

### The former revision

[image: The former revision]

### The final revision

[image: The final revision]

Quite clearly the annotation highlighting "01 Open a PDF from mail or web" is removed in the final revision.

Thus, your observation is at least incomplete, at least Adobe Reader does not show the removed annotation. Please indicate which viewers falsely do.

---

Furthermore inspecting the incremental update in the document it does look alright. There is just a small peculiarity, the cross reference entry for the single changed object points to the CRLF before the object, not the object itself.

Any viewer unable to cope with this will oftentimes have problems. Viewers actually are known to ignore much worse problems.